Multiple requests across the pods
I have a Kubernetes deployment with two pods running a PHP application. When I try to open a script that runs for more than 10 seconds, the request gets reinitiated, and the script runs multiple times across both pods.
The script is placed at the root directory of the application (For e.g, test.php). To execute the script, you can just open domain.com/test.php in the browser.
Here's the script:
<?php
error_log('start pod x'); // x is the pod name
sleep(11);
error_log('end pod x');
return;

The logs show the request being handled three times by both pods. This behavior is consistent but unexpected. I have checked the Ingress, deployment definition, and Apache configuration for the PHP application but couldn't find the cause.
Example of the logs:

I'm unsure whether the issue lies within the application or the infrastructure. Has anyone encountered this behavior before, or can provide insights into what might be causing this?

I've run into similar symptoms around HTTP timeouts, but these are more commonly around 60 seconds than around 10.  (As a rule of thumb, I tend to recommend trying to get the maximum HTTP request latency under 1 second, which occasionally means adding some sort of asynchronous-completion mechanism to your system.)  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve], which may make it more obvious where a timeout would be added?

Thank you for your reply! Yes, the timeout for retry requests is surprisingly short, and I have suggested to the other team to reduce the latency of the request. However, the behavior of the ghost request is still quite bizarre. I am trying to figure out which part of the system is initiating the request. Also I have edited the question to include more details. Hope it helps!

Do you have some form of load balancer before your pods? This looks like some form of whatchdog to me that sends a "retry later again" in case a 10 seconds timeout is reached (in the load balancer, not the http server or client).

None that I know of, it's a NodePort that direct the request to the script. In the Pods, there are one login-proxy which is serviced by keykloak-gatekeeper, the keykloak whitelisted the script URL. So the request will go to the script through the proxy. Weird enough, the repeated request behavior stops once you close the tab in the browser.
